# How do I know if Image is playing or has finished in Kivy?

Tags: python, image, animation, kivy

I'm using a zip file with a bunch of jpg files to show an animation because loading a gif file is too slow. I'd like to change the current screen if an animation reaches the end. How do I know if Image is still playing the animation? Is there any better way than setting a timer based on the animation's fps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to capture that information. but here is an ugly hack.

If you set `anim_loop` to non zero for the `Image` and add a `loop_count` and an `on_texture` callback like this:

```
Image:
    loop_count: 0
    source: 'elephant.zip'
    anim_delay: 0.05
    anim_loop: 1
    on_texture: app.on_texture(self)
```

Then an `on_texture()` method in the `App` can determine if the animation has completed:

```
def on_texture(self, img):
    if img._coreimage.anim_index + 1 == len(img._coreimage.image.textures):
        # one animation loop complete
        img.loop_count += 1
        if img.loop_count == img.anim_loop:
            print('animation complete')
```